# How to send text message by LAN using Net.Sockets

Tags: c#, .net, sendmessage, lan, local-network

Does anybody know how to send text message in C# by LAN cable?

I know how to do it by Internet with Net.Sockets, but how can I send data over a LAN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same deal (in fact, *exactly* the same), except instead of specifying a remote address, specify the address of another machine in your LAN. On most home networks, this is usually an address that begins with `192.168`. or  `10.0`.

Comment: Aha. And Can I send data with UDP and TCP by Lan too. Or only for UDP?

Comment: @FewCen: Both protocols will work.